# Playing Probability with a Biased Coin

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose you are playing a coin game with a biased coin. Suppose you flip that coin $n$ times where $n$ is greater than $4$. Let $p$ be the probability that there is a head. Now, let $Z(3,n)$ be the number of consecutive three heads in $n$ trials. So what I mean by this is for example, those 3 consecutive heads could be $HHHT,THHH,$ or $THHHT$.

What is the expectation of $Z(3,n)$? What if we generalize this to let $m$ be the number of consecutive heads. Then what would be the expectation of $Z(m,n)$?

Comment: In HHHHT are there two instances of three consecutive heads, or none?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the counting works so that HHHHHHT will have 4 "HHH"s, where basically you count 1 if you find HHH in spaces a,a+1,a+2

In that case, think about this:

Number of HHH's = Number of HHH's in spaces 1,2,3 + Number of HHH's in spaces 2,3,4 + Number of HHH's in spaces 3,4,5 + ... + Number of HHH's in spaces n-2,n-1,n

As Expectation is linear:

E[Number of HHH's] = E[Number of HHH's in spaces 1,2,3] + E[Number of HHH's in spaces 2,3,4] + E[Number of HHH's in spaces 3,4,5] + ... + E[Number of HHH's in spaces n-2,n-1,n]

The number of HHH's can only be 1 or zero for a particular triplet of spaces.

Now the expectations are not conditional in the above expression, so the expectations can be calculation independently

E[Number of HHH's in spaces a,a+1,a+2] = 1 with probability $p^3$ and 0 with probability $1 - p^3$ = $p^3$

E[Number of HHH's] = $p^3 * (n-2)$ (There are n-2 such "triplets")

This you can generalize:

For E[m,n] it will be $p^m * (n - (m - 1))$