# Expected number of runs of heads of size $k$?

Tags: probability

I just completed this question, and I think I have a solution but I am not entirely sure. Here's the question, with an attempt later:

> A coin having a probability $p$ of landing on heads is flipped $n$ times. Compute the expected number of runs of heads of size $1$, of size $2$, and of size $k$, $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Here's my attempt at a solution which I am not entirely sure is correct:

> Let $x_i$ be $1$ if the $i$th coin flip is a tail that completes a run of size $k$ and $0$ otherwise. Doing so, we find that the following is true:
>           $$E[x_i] = p^k(1-p) \text{ for } i > k \text{, 0 otherwise}$$
>           Therefore, the expected number of runs of size $k$ is the following, where $y$ is $1$ if the last coin completes a run of $k$ heads and $0$ otherwise:
>           $$E[x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n + y] = \sum_{i = k+1}^{n}p^k(1-p) + p^k$$
>           Simplifying the above sum, we find that the following is the expected number of runs of size $k$:
>           $$E[x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n + y] = (n-k)p^k(1-p) + p^k$$

Does this work? If not, please explain?

Comment: To clear up the definition, suppose we toss $5$ times and get THHHT. Are there $2$ runs of size $2$, or $0$ runs of size $2$?

Comment: I had the same question, and the book doesn't specify unfortunately. I'm assuming it means exactly $k$ heads in a row.

Comment: @Birdman2246: But your expression for $E[x_i]$ doesn't correspond to exactly $k$ heads? Doesn't it need another factor $(1-p)$ for tails limiting it at the other end in that case?

Comment: @joriki: That's a good point. I think you are right. Let's wait and see what other people think.

Comment: I just realized that this should derive the formula for runs of $k$ or greater. If we need of exactly $k$, we can just subtract $k+1$. Or at least, that's what I think.

Comment: This question is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732756/playing-probability-with-a-biased-coin/1732780#1732780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to do this, because I love generating functions and I admire Marko's agility in manipulating them in interesting ways to solve difficult problems and his readiness to share it with us, but in this case using generating functions is what we'd call "shooting at sparrows with cannons" in German.

There are $n-k-1$ opportunities for a run of $k$ heads bounded by tails on either side, and $2$ opportunities for a run of $k$ heads at either end, bounded by tails on one side. By linearity of expectation, the expected number of runs is the sum of the probabilities of these runs, which is
$$
(n-k-1)p^k(1-p)^2+2p^k(1-p)=(n-k)p^k(1-p)^2+p^k(1-p^2)\;.
$$

Comment: You are being too kind in your introductory remark. I suspected something of the sort when I saw the simplicity of the answer. Thanks and (+1)! Can you also do the case when runs are not maximal i.e. $THHHT$ contains two runs of length two? This should give rise to some interesting generating functions.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Yes, just leave off the factors of $(1-p)$ that limit the runs. The expected number of runs of length $k$ is $(n-k+1)p^k$, since there are $n-k+1$ opportunities for such a run and the probability is $p^k$ in each case.

Comment: Very simple indeed.

Comment: I verified your second formula using generating functions. In the future I will remember to vet the appropriateness of a potential proceeding before starting to work on a problem. It was fun computing the second generating function using Maple.

Comment: Just Curios: Why is the last term $1-p^2$? I feel like it should just be $1-p$.

Comment: @Birdman2246: On the left-hand side it's $(1-p)$, as you expect. The $1-p^2$ is just the result of an algebraic simplification. Are you asking "why" with respect to the algebraic manipulations, or in the sense of how we can interpret that term probabilistically?

Answer (score 1):

We use a trivariate generating  function with $z$ and $w$ marking runs
of heads and tails resp. and $v$ marking runs of heads of size $k.$ In
the following  we assume that  $k$ refers to  the exact length  of the
run, with no short runs embedded  in longer ones, i.e. the extent of a
run is maximal.

We obtain

$$G(z,w,v)
= (1+z+\cdots+vz^k+z^{k+1}+\cdots)
\\ \times \left(\sum_{q\ge 0} 
(w+w^2+\cdots)^q (z+\cdots+vz^k+z^{k+1}+\cdots)^q\right)
(1+w+w^2+\cdots).$$

This is

$$\left((v-1)z^k+\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{w^q}{(1-w)^q}
\left((v-1)z^k+\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^q\right)
\frac{1}{1-w}$$

which simplifies to
$$\frac{(1-z)(v-1)z^k+1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-w((1-z)(v-1)z^k+z)/(1-w)/(1-z)}
\frac{1}{1-w}
\\ = \frac{(1-z)(v-1)z^k+1}
{(1-z)(1-w)-w((1-z)(v-1)z^k+z)}.$$

As a sanity check when we set $w=z$ and $v=1$ this turns into
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z)-z^2}
= \frac{1}{1-2z}.$$

This  says we  have $2^n$  strings of  length $n$  and the  check goes
through.

Introducing the probabilities we obtain
$$H(z, v) = G(pz, (1-p)z, v)
\\ = \frac{(1-pz)(v-1)p^kz^k+1}
{(1-pz)(1-(1-p)z)-(1-p)z((1-pz)(v-1)p^kz^k+pz)}.$$

Continuing with the usual procedure we compute

$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} H(z, v)\right|_{v=1}$$

to get

$$\frac{(1-pz) p^k z^k}
{(1-pz)(1-(1-p)z)-(1-p)z((1-pz)(v-1)p^kz^k+pz)}
\\ - \frac{(1-pz)(v-1)p^kz^k+1}
{((1-pz)(1-(1-p)z)-(1-p)z((1-pz)(v-1)p^kz^k+pz))^2}
\\ \times (- (1-p)z(1-pz)p^kz^k).$$

Fortunately there  is radical simplification  when we put  $v=1$ which
yields

$$\frac{(1-pz) p^k z^k}
{(1-pz)(1-(1-p)z)-(1-p)pz^2}
\\ - \frac{1}
{((1-pz)(1-(1-p)z)-(1-p)pz^2)^2}
\\ \times (- (1-p)z(1-pz)p^kz^k).$$

Now $$(1-pz)(1-(1-p)z)-(1-p)pz^2
= 1-z$$

so this becomes

$$\frac{(1-pz) p^k z^k}{1-z}
+ \frac{(1-p)z(1-pz)p^kz^k}{(1-z)^2}
\\ = p^k z^k \frac{(1-pz)^2}{(1-z)^2}
= p^k z^k \frac{1-2pz+p^2z^2}{(1-z)^2}.$$

Extracting coefficients from this we finally obtain

$$p^k 
\left([z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
- 2p [z^{n-k-1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}
+ p^2 [z^{n-k-2}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\right)
\\ = p^k
\left(n-k+1 - 2p(n-k) + p^2 (n-k-1)\right)
\\ = p^k (1-p)^2 n
+ p^k (1 - p^2 k - p^2 + 2pk - k)
\\ = p^k (1-p)^2 (n-k)
+ p^k(1-p^2).$$

The  formulae  that  were   presented  here  were  computed  by  total
enumeration as well as symbolically.

This was the Maple code.

```
V :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local gf, ind, d, cnt, runs, runq,
    cur, len, pos;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from 2^n to 2^(n+1)-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2);

        cur := d[1]; len := 1; runs := [];

        cnt := [0, 0]; cnt[cur+1] := 1;

        for pos from 2 to n+1 do
            if pos = n+1 or d[pos] <> cur then
                runs := [op(runs), [cur, len]];

                cur := d[pos]; len := 1;
            else
                len := len + 1;
            fi;

            if pos < n+1 then
                cnt[cur+1] := cnt[cur+1] + 1;
            fi;
        od;

        runq :=
        nops(select(r->r[1] = 1 and r[2] = k, runs));

        gf := gf  + z^cnt[2]*w^cnt[1]*v^runq;
    od;

    gf;
end;

G :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local gf, cf;

    gf := ((1-z)*(v-1)*z^k+1)
    /((1-z)*(1-w)-w*((1-z)*(v-1)*z^k+z));

    cf :=
    add(coeftayl(coeftayl(gf, z=0, q), w=0, n-q)
        *z^q*w^(n-q), q=0..n);

    expand(cf);
end;

H1A :=
proc(n, k)
    local cf;

    cf :=
    coeftayl(subs([z=p*z, w=(1-p)*z], V(n, k)), z=0, n);

    collect(expand(cf), v);
end;

H1 :=
proc(n, k)
    local cf;

    cf := subs([z=p, w=(1-p)], V(n, k));

    collect(expand(cf), v);
end;

H2 :=
proc(n, k)
    local gf;

    gf := ((1-p*z)*(v-1)*p^k*z^k+1)
    /((1-p*z)*(1-(1-p)*z)
      -(1-p)*z*((1-p*z)*(v-1)*p^k*z^k+p*z));

    collect(expand(coeftayl(gf, z=0, n)), v);
end;

DH1 :=
proc(k)
    local gf;

    gf := ((1-p*z)*(v-1)*p^k*z^k+1)
    /((1-p*z)*(1-(1-p)*z)
      -(1-p)*z*((1-p*z)*(v-1)*p^k*z^k+p*z));

    subs(v=1, diff(gf, v));
end;

DH2 :=
proc(k)
    (1-p*z)*p^k*z^k/((1-p*z)*(1-(1-p)*z) - (1-p)*p*z^2)
    - 1/((1-p*z)*(1-(1-p)*z)- (1-p)*p*z^2)^2
    * (-(1-p)*z*(1-p*z)*p^k*z^k);
end;

DH3 :=
proc(k)
    p^k*z^k*(1-p*z)^2/(1-z)^2;
end;

X :=
proc(n, k)
    local gf;

    gf := V(n, k);

    subs(v=1, diff(subs([z=p, w=1-p], gf), v));
end;

XX :=
proc(n, k)
    p^k*(1-p)^2*n
    + p^k * (1-p^2*k-p^2+2*p*k-k);
end;

XXX :=
proc(n, k)
    p^k*(1-p)^2*(n-k) + p^k * (1-p^2);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here  is  the generating  function  for  runs  that are  not  maximal,
i.e.  substrings  of a  run  count towards  shorter  runs.   We use  a
trivariate generating function with $z$  and $w$ marking runs of heads
and tails resp. and $v$ marking runs of heads of size $k.$

We obtain

$$G(z,w,v)
= (1+z+\cdots+vz^k+v^2z^{k+1}+\cdots)
\\ \times \left(\sum_{q\ge 0} 
(w+w^2+\cdots)^q (z+\cdots+vz^k+v^2z^{k+1}+\cdots)^q\right)
(1+w+w^2+\cdots).$$

This is

$$\left(\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}+vz^k\frac{1}{1-vz}\right)
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{w^q}{(1-w)^q}
\left(z\frac{1-z^{k-1}}{1-z}+vz^k\frac{1}{1-vz}\right)^q\right)
\frac{1}{1-w}$$

which simplifies to
$$\frac{1 - z^k - vz + vz^{k+1} + vz^k - vz^{k+1}}{(1-z)(1-vz)}
\\ \times \frac{1}
{1-w(z - z^k - vz^2 + vz^{k+1} + vz^{k} - vz^{k+1})
/(1-z)/(1-vz)/(1-w)}
\\ \times \frac{1}{1-w}
\\ = \frac{1 - z^k - vz + vz^{k}}
{(1-z)(1-vz)(1-w)-w(z - z^k - vz^2 + vz^k)}.$$

As a sanity check when we set $w=z$ and $v=1$ this turns into
$$\frac{1-z^k-z+z^{k}}
{(1-z)^3-z(z - z^k - z^2 + z^k)}
\\ = \frac{1-z}{(1-z)^3 - z^2(1-z)}
= \frac{1}{(1-z)^2 - z^2}
= \frac{1}{1-2z}.$$

This  says we  have $2^n$  strings of  length $n$  and the  check goes
through.

Continuing with the usual procedure we compute

$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} G(z, w, v)\right|_{v=1}$$

to get for the derivative

$$\frac{z^k-z}{(1-z)(1-vz)(1-w)-w(z - z^k - vz^2 + vz^k)}
\\ - \frac{1 - z^k - vz + vz^{k}}
{((1-z)(1-vz)(1-w)-w(z - z^k - vz^2 + vz^k))^2}
\times (-z(1-z)(1-w) + w (z^2-z^k)).$$

Evaluating at $v=1$ we have

$$(1-z)(1-vz)(1-w) - w(z - z^k - vz^2 + vz^k)
\\ = (1-z)^2 (1-w) - w(z-z^2)
= (1-z)(1-w-z)$$

and obtain
$$\frac{z^k-z}{(1-z)(1-w-z)}
\\ - \frac{1}{(1-z)(1-w-z)^2}
(-z(1-z)(1-w) + w (z^2-z^k))
\\ = \frac{z^k(1-z)}{(1-z)(1-w-z)^2}
= \frac{z^k}{(1-w-z)^2}.$$

Introducing the probabilities we find

$${\large \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} G(z, w, v)
\right|_{v=1, z=pz, w=(1-p)z} 
= \frac{p^k z^k}{(1-(1-p)z-pz)^2}
= \frac{p^k z^k}{(1-z)^2}}.$$

Extracting coefficients we finally have the answer
$$[z^n] \frac{p^k z^k}{(1-z)^2}
= p^k [z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} 
= p^k (n-k+1).$$

The  formulae  that  were   presented  here  were  computed  by  total
enumeration as well as symbolically.

This was the Maple code.

```
V :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local gf, ind, d, cnt, runs, run, runq,
    cur, len, pos;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from 2^n to 2^(n+1)-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2);

        cur := d[1]; len := 1; runs := [];

        cnt := [0, 0]; cnt[cur+1] := 1;

        for pos from 2 to n+1 do
            if pos = n+1 or d[pos] <> cur then
                runs := [op(runs), [cur, len]];

                cur := d[pos]; len := 1;
            else
                len := len + 1;
            fi;

            if pos < n+1 then
                cnt[cur+1] := cnt[cur+1] + 1;
            fi;
        od;

        runq := 0;

        for run in runs do
            if run[1] = 1 and run[2] >= k then
                runq := runq + 1+run[2]-k;
            fi;
        od;

        gf := gf  + z^cnt[2]*w^cnt[1]*v^runq;
    od;

    gf;
end;

S :=
proc(k)
    local gf;

    gf := (1-z^k-v*z+v*z^k)
    /((1-z)*(1-v*z)*(1-w)
      -w*(z-z^k-v*z^2+v*z^k));

    factor(subs([w=z, v=1], gf));
end;

G :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local gf, cf;

    gf := (1-z^k-v*z+v*z^k)
    /((1-z)*(1-v*z)*(1-w)
      -w*(z-z^k-v*z^2+v*z^k));

    cf :=
    add(coeftayl(coeftayl(gf, z=0, q), w=0, n-q)
        *z^q*w^(n-q), q=0..n);

    expand(cf);
end;


X := (n, k) -> subs(v=1, diff(subs([z=p, w=1-p], V(n,k)), v));
XX := (n, k) -> p^k*(n-k+1);
```